# Import error when trying to import tensorflow with gpu

Tags: python, tensorflow, gpu

```
ImportError: libcuda.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.
```

This error is appeared when import `tensorflow`.
I need to know steps to solve this problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are using TensorFlow with GPU, you need to install CUDA and cuDNN. Please follow instructions on https://www.tensorflow.org/install/

If you have already install CUDA and cuDNN, but still get this error, then you probably forgot to export your libraries: for Linux, you may need to set LD_LIBRARY_PATH to include CUDA libraries.

Comment: How can i set LD_LIBRARY_PATH?

Comment: Something like: `$ export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/cuda/extras/CUPTI/lib64/:/opt/intel/ipp/lib/intel64_lin:/usr/local/lib:/usr/local/cuda/extras/CUPTI/lib64/:/opt/intel/ipp/lib/intel64_lin:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH`

Comment: The previous problem is solved but                                              
 ImportError: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.16' not found    appears when i write import  tensorflow

Answer (score 0):

After installing TensorFlow 1.11 GPU via Anaconda "conda install tensorflow-gpu" I also experienced the same problem.  Before TF 1.11 I used TF 1.04.  Just before the TF update I updated Nvidia Driver to the version 396 through ppa.

There was no trace of libcuda.so.1 in my entire linux.

After many trials, the problem was solved when I changed the nvidia driver to 390. The 390 version inserted libcuda.so.1 to /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu directory, which evidently solved the problem.